# IE9 dropdown list issue

Tags: jquery, html

I have an issue with a dynamic dropdownlist in IE9.

I have a table, and one of the columns gets filled out with combos, one combo per row, and each of those combos is created with a HTML 5.0 code, like this:

```
<select id="cboABC0" class="RetrieveList cboABC" data-index="0" data-info="3" name="cboABC">
<option selected="selected" value="N">Select</option>
<option value="P">Partial</option>
<option value="C">Complete</option>
<option value="CA">Cancelled</option>
</select>
</td>
```

I want something to happen when one of the options is selected in the dropdown list, depending on the selected option, and for that, I have tried different ways of using the events of the class RetrieveList, with JQuery:

```
$(".RetrieveList").live(''click'',function(event){      

var val_info = $(this).attr("data-info"); 
var val_index = $(this).attr("data-index");

var sOptionSelected = $(this).val();

alert(sOptionSelected);

// Here is where I want to do something , depending on the selected option.

});
```

With the "live click", at least the clicking event gets "fired", but it doesn't recognize what I choose, it stays with the last option I had chosen, for example if nothing has been selected and I open the combo, move to another option and click that option, it goes to the click event, but the value that returns with $(this).val() is the previous not the one just selected.
In the other hand, if I select the option with the arrow keys and then give click, id does recognize the new value. It's like if it only recognizes the change of "click" but not of value.

I have tried with "bind click", "live change" and "bind change" and with those options, the click doesn't even get "fired".

Again, this all happens with IE9, with Mozilla, I haven't had any major problems.

If anybody could please help me with this issue, I will greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance,

Regards!

Brenda

Answer (score 2):

First off, you have `''click''` when it should be just `'click'`. I wouldn't use `click` anyway, instead use `change` so it fires whenever the list changes and not just when the user clicks it. `click` will fire even if you just click it without making a different selection (the click to view all the dropdown items)

Fixing that, it works in all browsers for me.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UDZX5/)

Comment: Thanks Sachleen, I tried your suggestion, and used 'change' instead of 'click' but the event only gets fired if I change the option with the keys and give "enter", it never gets fired if I pick it using the mouse, any ideas of why this could be happening? Thanks!

Comment: Does the demo I provided work as it should? If so, the issue is somewhere else in your code and we'll need to see that to isolate it. Check the console (Wrench > Tools > Javascript Console in Chrome) for any errors

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
    $(".RetrieveList").live('change',function(event){      

var val_info = $(this).attr("data-info"); 
var val_index = $(this).attr("data-index");

var sOptionSelected = $(this).val();

alert(sOptionSelected);

// Here is where I want to do something , depending on the selected option.

});
```

Comment: Thanks chrisvillanueva, I tried your suggestion, and used 'change' instead of 'click' but the event only gets fired if I change the option with the keys and give "enter", it never gets fired if I pick it using the mouse, any ideas of why this could be happening? Thanks!

Comment: hi.  that code works for me.  please view the demo here:  http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/7PBWE/   there might be a problem somewhere else.